# How to parse this soap response

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm using the an API, and I get this kind of response:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<env:Header>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
<ns1:processRequestResponse xmlns:ns1='ejb.store.microsoft.com'>
<result>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <CRMMessage language="en_US" currency="USD"  isTrustedSAT="false" hostversion="1.00"><RequestCode>GetCustomer</RequestCode><ResponseCode>A</ResponseCode><ResultSet><ResultSetMetaData><RSColumn name="PrimaryPOSRef" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn><RSColumn name="FirstName" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn><RSColumn name="LastName" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn><RSColumn name="EmailAddress" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn><RSColumn name="MobilePhoneNumber" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn><RSColumn name="Gender" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn><RSColumn name="PostalCode" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn><RSColumn name="PMACode" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn></ResultSetMetaData><Rows><Row id="11551"><Col>0331200000000058</Col><Col>test</Col><Col>Test</Col><Col>test@test.com</Col><Col>0412345678</Col><Col>M</Col><Col>2000</Col><Col>test</Col></Row></Rows></ResultSet></CRMMessage> 
</result>
</ns1:processRequestResponse>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

what useful is the section between

```
<result></result>
```

How can I parse this XML ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+soap+response+php

Comment: That's not (valid) XML, due to the declaration as a child of the result element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and immidiate way is to parse the xml into array and then use tags as array index. You can find some php classes related to this here:

http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=xml++array&restrict[0]=C&restrict[1]=B&restrict[2]=D&forums=F&go_search=1&advanced=1